# ERROR TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function, openlayers 3

Tags: typescript, openlayers-3

I am trying to buffer a vector feature in openlayers 3, however I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
var radius = 5,
        format = new ol.format.WKT()
    var reader = new jsts.io.WKTReader()
    var geom = reader.read(format.writeGeometry(this.Feature.getGeometry()))
    var buffered = geom.buffer(radius)

    var writer = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter()
    buffered = writer.write(buffered)
var nfeature = {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: buffered,
    properties: {}
}
this.VectorOverlay.getSource().addFeature(nfeature) <= error
```

Comment: You propably use a wrong version of jsts. Better make a fiddle to demonstrate your case

Comment: Where can I get the different versions of jsts? Ill attempt all versions

Comment: If you use the latest ol3 version use this jsts version-->https://cdn.rawgit.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/gh-pages/1.2.0/jsts.min.js. Unless you provide a fiddle I can only guess what may your problem is. Help to get helped.